# Await isn't waiting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Hi I've got two functions. They're called inside another function. And I need the second function execute after the first is done.

I'm sorry this is probably a very simple question, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around promises and async/await in js. Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working.

```
async function addDetails(){
    const sub = await getSession();
    // now wait for firstFunction to finish...
    addProfileDetails(sub);
  };
```

I have debug/logging statements in both. So I know that addProfileDetails is being executed before the variable sub is defined.

I'm using react native and node.js

EDIT:

```
export function getSession() {
  console.log("checking user ...............................................")
  Auth.currentSession().then(res=>{
      console.log("retrieving token");
      let accessToken = res.getAccessToken()
      let payload = accessToken.payload;
      console.log(`sub: ${payload.sub}`)
      return payload.sub
  }) 
};
```

This is my getSession() function. It also needs to be async?

Comment: Is getsession async?

Comment: Also, how do you know it isn't waiting?

Comment: It looks like the problem is inside your getSession() function. Pls. post source of getSession()

Comment: ```getSession``` Has to return a promise. Also a tip is to wrap your async code in a try/catch. The catch part will fire when the promise.reject() is called from getSession

Comment: I updated the post with the getSession() function.

I know it's not waiting because i have debug statements in both that execute concurrently. and in one it says the sub variable undefined, but then the get session logs the sub variable

Comment: current `getSession()` function don't return anything.

Answer (score 5):

You must return a promise from the function that you want to await

```
export function getSession() {
  console.log("checking user ...............................................")
  return Auth.currentSession().then(res=>{
      console.log("retrieving token");
      let accessToken = res.getAccessToken()
      let payload = accessToken.payload;
      console.log(`sub: ${payload.sub}`)
      return payload.sub
  }) 
};
```

Comment: This is the right answer.  Just return the promise so that the caller can use that promise to know when it's done and get its resolved value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your **getSession**

```
export function getSession() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("checking user ...............................................")
      Auth.currentSession().then(res=>{
      console.log("retrieving token");
      let accessToken = res.getAccessToken()
      let payload = accessToken.payload;
      console.log(`sub: ${payload.sub}`)
      resolve(payload.sub)
  })

};
```

Comment: I think `Auth.currentSession()` is a Promise , you returned Promise's Promise. I dont preffer this.

Comment: This is a promise anti-pattern (wrapping an existing promise in another promise) and the reasons to avoid it are many.  Among others, you don't do proper error propagation. See Alberto's answer for the proper solution.